# "Lights Out" Validity Checker

Tags: java, solver

I've been trying to code a game of "Lights Out" and have coded the game and its mechanics. My only issue is with the problem that every puzzle is not solvable. I have attempted to code a method to check the puzzle it creates for solvability, but when I run the game, nothing shows up now. The game never runs. I believe that it is stuck somewhere within the checkValidity() method, but I am not sure where. Any help?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.util.Random;

public class buildBoard {
    public static JButton[][] board = new JButton[5][5];
    public static boolean[][] color = new boolean[5][5];;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static UIManager UIManager = new UIManager();

    public static int boardWidth, boardHeight, numBlack, moves = 0;

    public static String bottomRow = "";
    public static boolean isSolvable = false;

    public buildBoard(final int width, final int height){

        boardWidth = width;
        boardHeight = height;

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));

        boolean[][] color = new boolean[boardWidth][boardHeight];

        for(int a = 0; a < width; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < height; b++){
                board[a][b] = new JButton();
            }
        }
        generateLights();
        while(isSolvable == false){
        generateLights();
        checkValidity();
        if(isSolvable == false){
                for(int c = 0; c < boardWidth; c++){
                    for(int d = 0; d < boardHeight; d++){
                        color[c][d] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(int a = 0; a < width; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < height; b++){    
                board[a][b].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        moves++;
                        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
                                if(e.getSource()==board[i][j]){ //gameButtons[i][j] was clicked
                                    if(board[i][j].getBackground() == Color.BLUE){
                                        board[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        board[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                                    }
                                    if(j > 0 && (board[i][j-1].getBackground() == Color.BLUE)){
                                        board[i][j-1].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                                    }
                                    else if(j > 0){
                                        board[i][j-1].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                                    }
                                    if(i > 0 && board[i-1][j].getBackground() == Color.BLUE){
                                        board[i-1][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                                    }
                                    else if (i > 0){
                                        board[i-1][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                                    }
                                    if(i < width-1 && board[i+1][j].getBackground() == Color.BLUE){
                                        board[i+1][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                                    }
                                    else if(i < width-1){
                                        board[i+1][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                                    }
                                    if(j < height-1 && board[i][j+1].getBackground() == Color.BLUE){
                                        board[i][j+1].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                                    }
                                    else if(j < height-1){
                                        board[i][j+1].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                                    }
                                    checkIfWon();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception e) { } 
            frame.add(board[a][b]);
        }
    }

    frame.setTitle("Lights Out!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public void checkIfWon(){
    int numBlack = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < boardWidth; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < boardHeight; j++){
            if(board[i][j].getBackground() == Color.BLACK){
                numBlack++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(numBlack == 25){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hooray! You Won!\nYou won in " + moves + " moves.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void checkValidity(){     
    for(int j = 0; j < boardHeight - 1; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < boardWidth; i++){
            if(color[i][j] == true){
                if(color[i][j] == true){
                    color[i][j] = false;
                }
                else{
                    color[i][j] = true;
                }
                if(j > 0 && color[i][j+1] == true){
                    color[i][j+1] = false;
                }
                else if(j > 0){
                    color[i][j+1] = true;
                }
                if(i > 0 && color[i-1][j+1] == true){
                    color[i-1][j+1] = false;
                }
                else if (i > 0){
                    color[i-1][j+1] = true;
                }
                if(i < boardWidth-1 && color[i+1][j+1] == true){
                    color[i+1][j+1] = false;
                }
                else if(i < boardWidth-1){
                    color[i+1][j+1] = true;
                }
                if(j < boardHeight-2 && color[i][j+2] == true){
                    color[i][j+2] = false;
                }
                else if(j < boardHeight-2){
                    color[i][j+2] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int c = 0; c < boardWidth; c++){
        if(color[4][c] == true){
            bottomRow += "1";
        }
        else{
            bottomRow += "0";
        }
    }
    if(bottomRow.equals("10001") || bottomRow.equals("01010") || bottomRow.equals("11100") || bottomRow.equals("00111") || bottomRow.equals("10110") || bottomRow.equals("01101") || bottomRow.equals("11011")){
        isSolvable = true;
    }
    else{
        isSolvable = false;
    }
}

public static void generateLights(){
    Random random = new Random();

    for(int a = 0; a < boardWidth; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b < boardHeight; b++){
            if(random.nextInt(99)+1 > 75){
                board[a][b].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                color[a][b] = true;
            }else{
                board[a][b].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                color[a][b] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

    public static void main(String []args){
        new buildBoard(5, 5);
    }
}
```

The checkValidity() method is the issue, and is posted here (rest of code with the method is above, just in case):

```
public static void checkValidity(){     
    for(int j = 0; j < boardHeight - 1; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < boardWidth; i++){
            if(color[i][j] == true){
                if(color[i][j] == true){
                    color[i][j] = false;
                }
                else{
                    color[i][j] = true;
                }
                if(j > 0 && color[i][j+1] == true){
                    color[i][j+1] = false;
                }
                else if(j > 0){
                    color[i][j+1] = true;
                }
                if(i > 0 && color[i-1][j+1] == true){
                    color[i-1][j+1] = false;
                }
                else if (i > 0){
                    color[i-1][j+1] = true;
                }
                if(i < boardWidth-1 && color[i+1][j+1] == true){
                    color[i+1][j+1] = false;
                }
                else if(i < boardWidth-1){
                    color[i+1][j+1] = true;
                }
                if(j < boardHeight-2 && color[i][j+2] == true){
                    color[i][j+2] = false;
                }
                else if(j < boardHeight-2){
                    color[i][j+2] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int c = 0; c < boardWidth; c++){
        if(color[4][c] == true){
            bottomRow += "1";
        }
        else{
            bottomRow += "0";
        }
    }
    if(bottomRow.equals("10001") || bottomRow.equals("01010") || bottomRow.equals("11100") || bottomRow.equals("00111") || bottomRow.equals("10110") || bottomRow.equals("01101") || bottomRow.equals("11011")){
        isSolvable = true;
    }
    else{
        isSolvable = false;
    }
}

public static void generateLights(){
    Random random = new Random();

    for(int a = 0; a < boardWidth; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b < boardHeight; b++){
            if(random.nextInt(99)+1 > 75){
                board[a][b].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                color[a][b] = true;
            }else{
                board[a][b].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                color[a][b] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger or profiler to figure out exactly where it's stuck (e.g. just run it for a while in the debugger and then pause it, and see where the stack is at that point). I'd guess it's going into an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: You could put trace code in there that changes the caption on your windows so that you know where it stops.

Comment: Please refine your question to point to the most relevant piece of your code.

Comment: Line 172 (bottomRow += "0";) I don't know what to do about this...

Comment: Why all the downvotes and votes to close? This seems like a legitimate question and the OP even managed to point to the area of code where the actual problem is

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed in your validity checker, specifically in that your bottowRow is **never** valid.

On the first run you generate a 5 character string which is invalid, then you start again but you never reset that string and instead keep appending to it so it constantly grows.  I modified your programme to output every bottom row it checks and this is what I get...

```
Checking bottom row: 00001
Checking bottom row: 0000100000
Checking bottom row: 000010000000000
Checking bottom row: 00001000000000000000
Checking bottom row: 0000100000000000000000000
Checking bottom row: 000010000000000000000000000000
Checking bottom row: 00001000000000000000000000000000001
```

You need to reset the data structures to be empty when you regenerate the board.

As a stylistic thing, your overuse of class level variables is hurting your ability to debug here, you should try to keep your data as local as possible.  For example, drop the use of statics and make things instance variables instead and have your methods return data instead of just setting it

Comment: I tried to add a reset of bottomRow before the loop and before the call of the method, but no change. Thanks for the style tip by the way, but for some reason I have always seemed to have trouble with returns.

Comment: Without the reset there's never a point generating further sequences.  The bottomRow variable is never read outside of the method so get rid of public static String bottomRow = ""; and instead include String bottomRow = "" in the checkValidity method above where you first use it.  This won't fix your problem entirely as you have a problem in your actual logic inside that method as well

Comment: Specifically your checkValidity method is modifying the data it is supposed to be checking, so no matter what values come in in your color array, it gets switched to either [false, false, false, false, false] or [false, false, false, false, true] - it never generates a correct sequence.  Without knowing what it is you're actually trying to do I won't be able to offer more help

Comment: Sorry about not replying, i was very busy this weekend. Anyways, what i am trying to do is to have the checkValidity() method determine whether the generated matrix is a solvable lights out game. I am doing this by having the computer "play" the puzzle out, until it gets to a point where the validity can be easily checked (the sequences that bottomRow is checked against).